# Vue.js DataTables: Render method in click function not working

Tags: datatables, vuejs3

I'm working on a Vue.js project where I use DataTables to display data. I have a column with a render method that includes a click function, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. When I click the rendered element, nothing happens. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
<script setup>
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3';
import DataTablesCore from 'datatables.net';

DataTable.use(DataTablesCore);

const options = ref({
      columns: [
        {
          data: 'id', title: 'Action',
          render: (data) => {
            return  `
              <div class="flex items-center px-6 py-4 gap-3">
                <div class="cursor-pointer bg-green-600 p-1 rounded-md">
                  <svg class="w-[20px] h-[20px] fill-[#d1e5d4] " viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M410.3 231l11.3-11.3-33.9-33.9-62.1-62.1L291.7 89.8l-11.3 11.3-22.6 22.6L58.6 322.9c-10.4 10.4-18 23.3-22.2 37.4L1 480.7c-2.5 8.4-.2 17.5 6.1 23.7s15.3 8.5 23.7 6.1l120.3-35.4c14.1-4.2 27-11.8 37.4-22.2L387.7 253.7 410.3 231zM160 399.4l-9.1 22.7c-4 3.1-8.5 5.4-13.3 6.9L59.4 452l23-78.1c1.4-4.9 3.8-9.4 6.9-13.3l22.7-9.1v32c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h32zM362.7 18.7L348.3 33.2 325.7 55.8 314.3 67.1l33.9 33.9 62.1 62.1 33.9 33.9 11.3-11.3 22.6-22.6 14.5-14.5c25-25 25-65.5 0-90.5L453.3 18.7c-25-25-65.5-25-90.5 0zm-47.4 168l-144 144c-6.2 6.2-16.4 6.2-22.6 0s-6.2-16.4 0-22.6l144-144c6.2-6.2 16.4-6.2 22.6 0s6.2 16.4 0 22.6z"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
                <div class="cursor-pointer bg-red-600 p-1 rounded-md" @click="handleDeleteClick(${data})">
                  <svg class="w-[20px] h-[20px] fill-[#d1e5d4]" viewBox="0 0 448 512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path d="M135.2 17.7C140.6 6.8 151.7 0 163.8 0H284.2c12.1 0 23.2 6.8 28.6 17.7L320 32h96c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H32C14.3 96 0 81.7 0 64S14.3 32 32 32h96l7.2-14.3zM32 128H416V448c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H96c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V128zm96 64c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V432c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V208c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm96 0c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V432c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V208c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm96 0c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V432c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V208c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16z"></path>
                  </svg>  
                </div>
              </div>
            `
          }
        }
...// another columns
],
      data: [],
      searching: false,
      lengthMenu: [10, 15, 25],
      pageLength: 10,
    });
const handleDeleteClick = (id) => {
      console.log('Delete button clicked for ID:', id);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: DataTable's `render` function interprets the passed string as HTML, not as a Vue template. In HTML, `@click` doesn't have any meaning. Internally, Vue compiles it into a `onclick` handler. Currently your question lacks context and essential debugging details. It's not clear how you've implemented DataTables + Vue and what versions you are using for each. Provide a *runnable* [mcve] if you need more help. Use codesandbox.io (or similar) if you need a node-like online environment.

Comment: You might find this example of [dynamic rendering](https://stackblitz.com/edit/datatables-net-vue3-reactive?file=src%2FApp.vue) in DataTables with Vue3 useful. Relevant [documentation here](https://datatables.net/blog/2022-06-22-vue#DataTables-API).

Comment: onMounted(() => {
      const edit = document.querySelector('#edit2'); // this id is test
      if(edit){
        console.log('hlsdfd')
        edit.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
      }
    })

    function handleClick() {
      console.log('Edit clicked!');
    }

Why I can't use like this?